# Jackson: How to deserialize 2 JSON fields into one combined property?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have documents in MongoDB which refer to other documents:

```
{ "_id": ..., "clientId": "foo123", "clientKind": "User", "otherProps": ... }
```

I need to turn these `client...` references into an object like (for your imagination):

```
new UserReference(id = "foo123")
```

or maybe

```
new Reference<User>(id = "foo123")
```

I.e. the `...Kind` is translated into a type (`User`), and the `...Id` simply into `id`.

How can I handle the 2 properties blended into the others?

I need to turn the 2 of the JSON fields into 1 reference property in Java (Kotlin).
They could be private and there could be a custom getter, but I would prefer Jackson to handle this for me.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`@JsonAlias`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) annotation that allows you to define additional property names? Or if the structures are different you might use intermediate classes and do the mapping yourself, or use a custom deserializer.

Comment: Aren't these two different POJOs that maybe extend the same base class (that aggregates all the common fields and also that declares the abstract method which builds your UserReference out of that specific instance)?

Comment: I have updated the question - removed the simple case, not to confuse.